# How to setTimeout during a loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, settimeout

I'm trying to change the last word in a sentence every nth second. I want to fade out the word inside a specific span, then replace the word, and finally fade in the new word.

I'm having troubles with the concurrent nature of Javascript. Regardless how I try I can't get my loop to pause execution after each word.

My latest attempt looks like this:

```js
  var shuffleSentences;

  $(function() {
    return shuffleSentences();
  });

  shuffleSentences = function() {
    var div, index, sentence, sentences;
    div = $(".sentences");
    sentences = div.data("sentences").split(";");
    sentence = div.html();
    index = sentences.indexOf(sentence);
    sentences.splice(index, 1);
    return $.each(sentences, function(i, sentence) {
      return setTimeout((function() {
        return div.fadeTo(500, 0.0, function() {
          div.html(sentence);
          return div.fadeTo(1000, 1.0, function() {
            if (sentences.length === i + 1) {
              console.log("Restart: " + i);
              return shuffleSentences();
            } else {
              return console.log("Don't restart: " + i);
            }
          });
        });
      }), 4000);
    });
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>We're at number <span class="sentences" data-sentences="one;two;three;four">two</span></p>
```

As you see word replacements do happen, but looking in the console it seems I'm doing it wrong.

Suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Main issue is that those setTimeouts will all run at basically the same time. The `each` loop doesn't wait for each one and will complete almost instantly

Comment: Also none of your use cases for `return` are legitimate. They are all redundant